# How to bold text in php contact form

Tags: php, contact-form

I'm using some php code for a contact form which I found on Google somewhere.
Everything is working just fine, the only thing I want to change is next.

Current result when I receive an email from my contact form it looks like this:

[image]

And I want it to look like this:

[image]

That means: Name, City, Number, Email, Message .. Those things I want to be BOLD when you receive the email.
And **Message:** should come under: Name, City, Number and Email.

Thanks

***UPDATE:***

Here is the PHP code:

> http:// akacija .ba/final/email/phpcode.txt

Comment: so what do you want us to do? If you want bold, then HTML 101 says `<b>...</b>` - `<strong>...</strong>`.

Comment: Without any code, we can't really give you the right code.

Comment: Sorry, i just realise that i forgot to give you the codes. I`ll edit my post right now and add those codes

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add html tags which makes the text bold to the form labels. use the `<strong>` tag around the label to make it darker.
Eg:

```
<label><strong>label to be darkened</strong</label>
```